# PowerShell Tee-Object not capturing debug lines in file

Tags: powershell, trace, io-redirection

I have a PowerShell script that runs via automation, so I need to capture the output of the script to a file, but I'd also like to capture the commands that were run, to give the output some context (I'd use `set -x` in a Linux shell script). I can't figure out how to capture those commands into the output file in Windows though; any help is much appreciated!

```
# script.ps1

Set-PSDebug -Trace 1
Write-Host "Hello, World!"
```

How I'm calling the script (from cmd):

```
$ powershell -command "./script.ps1 *>&1 | Tee-Object -FilePath ./output.txt"
```

Terminal output:

```
DEBUG:    2+  >>>> Write-Host "Hello, World!"
Hello, World!
```

output.txt file contents:

```
Hello, World!
```

You can see that the output file is missing the debug line that was shown in the terminal. **Ideally, I'd like the debug lines to only be in the output file (not the terminal output)**, but having the debug lines in both places would be fine too.

Note that PowerShell 5.1 is the version I have installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, **PowerShell's *tracing* output** (activated via [`Set-PSDebug`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-psdebug)) operates *outside* [PowerShell's system of output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection), so such output **cannot be captured from *inside* a PowerShell session.**<sup>[1]</sup>

However, **an *outside* caller of [PowerShell's CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)<sup>[2]</sup>, such as `cmd.exe` in your case, *does* receive tracing output via stdout** (the standard output stream)<sup>[3]</sup>, so you can use *`cmd.exe`*'s redirection to capture everything in a file and print it to the console afterwards.

A simplified example (from `cmd.exe`):

```
C:\>powershell -c "Set-PSDebug -Trace 1; Write-Host 'Hello, World!'" > output.txt & type output.txt

DEBUG:    1+ Set-PSDebug -Trace 1;  >>>> Write-Host 'Hello, World!'
Hello, World!
```

---

<sup>[1] Perhaps surprisingly, despite the word "Debug" in the cmdlet name, **tracing output does *not* go through stream number `5`, the debugging stream, the way that [`Write-Debug`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-debug) output does.**</sup>

<sup>[2] Note that you can use this technique of calling the CLI, invariably as a *child process*, from inside an existing PowerShell session as well, in which case that existing session acts as the outside caller. However, note that passing the command to execute via a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`), which is normally preferable, would *not* work in this case, because a script block-based invocation uses PowerShell's remoting infrastructure behind the scenes, which preserves the PowerShell-specific output streams (and also type fidelity, with limitations), so that the tracing output again goes straight to the console.</sup>

<sup>[3] Perhaps surprisingly, *all* of PowerShell's output streams - as well as to-console-only output such as produced by tracing - are by default mapped to an outside caller's *stdout* stream - including errors. While you can at least separate out errors *on demand* via a *stderr* redirection - `2>` - on the caller side, all remaining streams are invariably sent to stdout - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15669365/45375) and [GitHub issue #7989](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7989) for more information.</sup>