# Windows Powershell needs to print out information for a particular command regardless of whether it successfully executed or Not

Tags: powershell, iis, msbuild, windows-10, trace

I'm king of novice when it comes to Powershell.
I wanted to create Powershell scripts that are more verbose as it executes various commands.

For example in the following code, I want it to clearly display what it doing, and regardless of whether the command was executed successfully Or Not, I want it to print out the results of the execution of the command in question:

> Import-Module IISAdministration
>
> Stop-WebSite 'ArtemisDEV'
>
> $a = ".\blabBlah.csproj /t:Clean" Invoke-Expression "$msbuild $a"
>
> $b = ".\blabBlah.csproj /t:Build /p:Configuration=Dev"
> Invoke-Expression "$msbuild $b"

Could someone please modify the aforementioned code, and show it such a way that it will print out more verbose output statements?

Comment: Have a look at ```try { } catch { } finally { }``` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.1. the general pattern is ```try { <app code here> } catch { <error handling code here> } finally { <code to run regardless of whether app code worked or not> }```

Comment: @Johann, to avoid duplication I've decided to delete the answer here and have reposted it (with minor enhancements) to the linked duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70020655/45375).