# Convert bat file to powershell script

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a simple .bat file that executes a exe file and also passes some parameters in txt file. How do i acheive the same in powershell script (.ps1 file) ?

***.bat file content:***

```
@echo on
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C "C:\Program Files\BMC Software\AtriumCore\cmdb\server64\bin\cmdbdiag.exe" -u test -p test -s remedyar -t 41900 < "C:\Program Files\BMC Software\ARSystem\diserver\data-integration\batch\CleanupInputs.txt" > "C:\Program Files\BMC Software\ARSystem\diserver\data-integration\batch\Snow_Output\DailyOutput.log"
Exit 0
```

Comment: take a look at `Get-Help Start-Process -Examples`. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, `Start-Process` is virtually never the right tool for invoking _console_ applications (synchronously, with their streams connected to PowerShell's) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375).

Answer (score 2):

*Fundamentally*, you invoke console applications the same way in PowerShell as you do in `cmd.exe`, but there are important differences:

```bash
# If you really want to emulate `@echo ON` - see comments below.
Set-PSDebug -Trace 1 

# * PowerShell doesn't support `<` for *input* redirection, so you must
#   use Get-Content to *pipe* a file's content to another command.
# * `>` for *output* redirection *is* supported, but beware encoding problems:
#     * Windows PowerShell creates a "Unicode" (UTF-16LE) file,
#     * PowerShell (Core, v6+) a BOM-less UTF-8 file.
#     * To control the encoding, pipe to Out-File / Set-Content with -Encoding
# * For syntactic reasons, because your executable path is *quoted*, you must
#   invoke it via `&`, the call operator.
Get-Content "C:\..\CleanupInputs.txt" | 
  & "C:\...\cmdbdiag.exe" -u test -p test -s remedyar -t 41900 > "C:\...\DailyOutput.log"

# Turn tracing back off.
Set-PSDebug -Trace 0

exit 0
```

Note:

- For brevity I've replaced the long directory paths in your command with `...`
- **Character-encoding caveats**:

  - When PowerShell communicates with *external programs*, it only "speaks text" (and it generally never passes *raw bytes* through its pipelines (as of v7.2)), which therefore involves potentially multiple passes of encoding and decoding strings; specifically:
  - [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) doesn't just path a text file's raw bytes through, it *decodes* the content into *.NET strings* and then sends the content line by line through the pipeline. If the input file lacks a BOM, Windows PowerShell assumes the active ANSI encoding, whereas PowerShell (Core) 7+ assumes UTF-8; you can use the `-Encoding` parameter to specify the encoding explicitly.
  - Since the receiving command is an *external program* (executable), PowerShell (re)-*encodes* the lines before sending them to the program, based on the [`$OutputEncoding` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#outputencoding) , which defaults to ASCII(!) in Windows PowerShell, and UTF-8 in PowerShell (Core) 7+.
  - Since `>` - effectively an alias for [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) - is used to redirect the external program to a file, another round of decoding and encoding happens:

    - PowerShell first *decodes* the external program's output into .NET strings, based on the character encoding stored in `[Console]::OutputEncoding`, which defaults to the system's active OEM code page.
    - Then `Out-File` *encodes* the decoded strings based on *its* default encoding, which is UTF-16LE ("Unicode") in Windows PowerShell, and BOM-less UTF-8 in PowerShell (Core); to control the encoding, you need to use `Out-File` (or [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content)) explicitly and use its `-Encoding` parameter.

**See also:**

- [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection)
- `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-)
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375) discusses default encodings in both PowerShell editions; the short of it: they vary wildly in Windows PowerShell, but PowerShell (Core) 7+ now consistently used BOM-less UTF-8.

---

**Re execution tracing**: use of `@echo ON` in your batch file and how it compares to PowerShell's
[`Set-PSDebug`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-psdebug) `-Trace 1`:

- Batch files typically run with `@echo OFF` so as *not* to echo every command itself before printing its output.

  - `@echo ON` (or omitting an `@echo ON/OFF` statement altogether) can be helpful for *diagnosing problems* during execution, however.
  - `Set-PSDebug -Trace 1` is *similar* to `@echo ON`, but it has one disadvantage: the *raw source code* of commands is echoed, which means that you won't see the *value* of embedded variable references and expressions - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70020655/45375) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this, however it neither gave any error nor ran the exe file.

Comment: @Subbu, just to state the obvious: you need to use the _original_ paths when you actually try the code, not my abbreviated versions. If you do that, threre's no reason for the code to behave differently than your batch file - except perhaps for _character-encoding issues_ (please see my update). If the code doesn't work with the original paths, you need to describe (a) what you expect to happen and (b) what actually happens and how it differs from what you expect. Without that, everyone loses: (a) you won't get a solution and (b) if there's a flaw in the answer, it won't help future readers.