# How to uninstall django-rest-swagger?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pip, django-rest-swagger

Is there a simple or elegant way to uninstall django-rest-swagger on Windows 10?  I've recently started developing API's and creating documentation.  I found a tutorial that used the django-rest-swagger app.  After installing the app and doing more reading, I discovered that it was deprecated, and the developer's GitHub page recommends using drf-yasg.

I tried using "pip uninstall django-rest-swagger," and that echoed back that the app was uninstalled.  But, when I went into the virtual environment folder of the project, all the package folders were still there.  I also tried "pipenv uninstall django-rest-swagger", but it returned "pipenv is not recognized..." I spent a few hours reading the app docs, and googling "how to remove/ uninstall django-rest-swagger."  However, I didn't find anything useful.

Eventually, I gave up, and decided to do it the hard way.  I manually deleted all the installed files.  Fortunately, I hadn't updated my requirements.txt, so, I knew what was originally installed.  While this solution worked, it was somewhat time consuming.

Does django-rest-swagger have an internal uninstall command?  And does anyone know why "pip uninstall" didn't remove the app folders?

Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem when trying to uninstall directly from python. I managed to uninstall with 'pip uninstall django-rest-swagger' in the bash from the environment where it was installed. Hope that helps for linux users, I 'll see what I get on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just enable your virtualenv probably doing:

```
. /path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate
```

Then:

```
pip uninstall django-rest-swagger
```

Then go to `settings.py` and remove or comment the following line:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    #'rest_framework_swagger',
    ...
]
```

And finally remove or comment in `views.py` the import and code related with swagger library:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
#from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view

#schema_view = get_swagger_view(title='Pastebin API')

urlpatterns = [
#    url(r'^$', schema_view),
     ...
]
```

That's it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I see that your virtualenv activation script is in a Linux style pattern.  I'm currently using a Windows 10 OS.  However, when I ran the "pip uninstall django-rest-swagger" command, my virtual environment was activated, and I was in it.  The command echoed back that DRS was removed, but after running "pip freeze", it showed that all the packages were still there.

Comment: Can something like enable verbose info in Powershell help you to figure out what's wrong with pip uninstall? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41324882/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-with-verbose-output I'm not good at powershell.

Comment: That's a good question.  Unfortunately, you can't enter a virtual environment from Powershell.  But, I might be able to do something similar from CMD.  I'll try to give that a go.

Comment: Yes you can activate a virtualenv in powershell, take a look of this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365081/virtualenv-in-powershell

Comment: After doing some more reading and revisiting the code, I've decided to assume my problem was unique to my system and probably just a one-off.  @allexiusw answer is correct and, under normal circumstances, it should always work.  Many thanks to him and everyone else that looked into this problem.